# What I have to do to write and copile solidity on VS code

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

I am new and I want to start build code in VS code.

So I added solidity (by Joun Blanco) to my VS and I need something else? (i mean node and npm)

I am sorry for stiupid question but I do not found any tutorial about this.

**I heard about remix, but i prefer VS**

Comment: You can start from my [Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), and you can check the [long list of Ethereum developer tools, frameworks, components, services](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/l11cji/long_list_of_ethereum_developer_tools_frameworks/) form [/r/ethdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/).